# EOS JungleTestnet chain is not syncing

Tags: synchronization, eos

It was syncing, but it's not working now.
I didn't modify config.ini for nodeos after it's syncing.
Whenever I request 'cleos.sh get info', the resulting head_block_num is 1310498. Just like below:

```
root@eos-tnet:/opt/JungleTestnet# ./cleos.sh get info
{
  "server_version": "2ad41277",
  "chain_id": "038f4b0fc8ff18a4f0842a8f0564611f6e96e8535901dd45e43ac8691a1c4dca",
  "head_block_num": 1310498,
  "last_irreversible_block_num": 1305367,
  "last_irreversible_block_id": "0013eb171ef2f81fcc2140dd24af50034dde0f3e70d1491974b10c036aaf92bb",
  "head_block_id": "0013ff22028b05c04d545b7a74b9a462967eb5e764d1359db4857e2b58a33e75",
  "head_block_time": "2018-06-18T09:34:58.000",
  "head_block_producer": "dutcheosioxx",
  "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 200000000,
  "virtual_block_net_limit": 1048576000,
  "block_cpu_limit": 200000,
  "block_net_limit": 1048576,
  "server_version_string": "v1.2.2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[JungleTestnet 2.0 is live](https://monitor.jungletestnet.io/#home) They solved such issue with syncing node

New Chain ID: `e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473`

New Website: [`https://jungletestnet.io/`](https://jungletestnet.io/)

New Monitor: [`https://monitor.jungletestnet.io/`](https://monitor.jungletestnet.io/)

New Github: https://github.com/EOS-Jungle-Testnet

Answer (score 0):

1. Build v1.1.0 and start nodeos ( --genesis-json genesis.json --delete-all-blocks to start fresh)
2. Let it sync to around block 10.000.000 (don't know the exact required block nr, but did it around that number)
3. Stop nodeos (ctrl+c)
4. Build v1.2.2 and start nodeos (WITHOUT --genesis-json and --delete-all-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

check this site `day by day`: 
https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-Jungle-Testnet

Traps are on the way...